# Execute a function when Angular is finished rendering a controller's template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view

How can I execute a function after Angular has finished rendering my template for a controller?

Here is an example of the function I am trying to run. Since the view hasn't finished rendering, there are no elements matched by `$('.my-element')`.

```
function myFunction(){
  $('.my-element').css('color', 'red');
}
```

Comment: Are you using ng-view?

Comment: yes I am still using ng-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply listen this event if you are using ng-view.[ngView-viewContentLoaded](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) here you can get more idea about this event.

```
 $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    //Here your view content is fully loaded !!
    //Here you can write your custom logic which will execute after content loaded.      
     $('.my-element').css('color', 'red');
  });
```

Register this event in your parent controller.document clearly stated

```
Emitted every time the ngView content is reloaded.
```

See [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/isbTireh3w9OomDOvx87?p=preview)